# How to balance the root domain using NS records?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I have two load balancers that balance incoming traffic across multiple data centers. These work fine. I can test them out by doing an `nslookup example.com xIP`

I have now taken out DNS services with DYN.com to allow me to manage the DNS Zone file so that typing example.com will ask my load balancers what the IP address is to resolve.

Step 1 : the NS record for www.

I set up A records (glue) for ns1 & ns2, then the corresponding NS record to delegate the DNS lookup to the balancers instead of DYN.com's nameservers.

```
ns1.example.com A [ip address of load balancer 1]
ns2.example.com A [ip address of load balancer 1]
www.example.com NS ns1.example.com
www.example.com NS ns2.example.com
```

All is well - when I type www.example.com, the requests get delegated to my load balancers who provide the IP address of the endpoint and the connection is made successfully.

Step 2 : the NS record for root.

This is where I run into problems. I need customers to be able to type 'example.com' (without the www) and ALSO get delegated to the load balancers for the IP address.

However - of the research I have done, and through the DYN control panel, it seems to be not allowed to provide an NS record for the root - as this overrides the default NS servers.

How can i delegate both the root and the www. to my load balancers?

Comment: You don't. End of story. Make sure you are redirecting no-www to www.

Answer (score 1):

In your current setup, you cannot produce dynamic answers for your root domain. You have at least two different options on how to proceed:

- Create two different `A` records (and two different `AAAA` records if you want to be future proof) for your domain. Have both load balancers configured to redirect requests for your domain to the `www` subdomain.
- Host all DNS yourself. Get your own DNS servers put in the `NS` records for your domain right on the `TLD` servers.

You could also configure `SRV` records. But too few clients support it, for that to be viable as your only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Configure two A records for example.com?

```
0.0.0.1 A example.com.
0.0.0.2 A example.com.
```